# Diode question help here please

Tags: diodes

We have the circuit in the figure.I have to find the currents in the diodes and in the resistances R1 and R2.
The diodes are real and Vd=0.7 V

Awesome.

Here is the original figure

[image]

I have drawn the circuit and I have replaced the diodes with the voltages

[image]

I apply the KVL in the first loop and I have -20+ 0.7+0.7 - I2R2=0  so I2 here is negative...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what are the diodes?
are the arrows supposed to be the diodes?

Comment: Are "awesome" diodes also invisible?

Comment: I have replaced the diodes in the figure with their voltages of 0.7 Volts

Comment: The arrows show the direction of the currents

Comment: I added the original figure

Comment: You are mixing different techniques together. You say KVL, but you are doing loop equations and not node equations. If you are doing KCL, your current directions need to be going in the same direction (either counter clockwise, or clockwise and not both)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all the diodes take 0.7V.

VR1 is parallel over D2 = 0.7V

VR2 = 20V- 2* 0.7V = 18.6V

With these values known you can calculate the currents

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why is  VR1 0.7 Volts?

Comment: over the diode there can be no more than 0.7V of voltage
the resistor is connected parallel over the max voltage of the diode 0.7V

so the voltage will be the same

Comment: I understand.I want to know,what Vi interval should I study to know when the diodes are on or off?

Comment: If there a voltage below the forward voltage (0.7V) then that voltage will also be over the diode
If the voltage rises above 0.7V there will only be 0.7V over the diode.
A diode is on (closed switch) if there is a voltage of 0.7V across the diode.
if it's less than 0.7V or a negative voltage the diode blocks current.

Comment: Does 20 Volt voltage influence that?

Comment: the voltage over d1 and d2 to will stay both 0.7V so 1.4V in total
Any voltage above 1.4V will be over R2. So with 30V there will be 28.6V over R2.

Answer (score 0):

In the direction of the current I2 is selected as you have drawn, It just should be negative. Your 20 volt battery (which is much higher than 0.7) drives all the currents clockwise.